# Unable Use backspace key on picturebox to delete line that i have drawn in C#

Tags: c#

This is what I had done so far. I have been searching for the codes and tried applying it back to my program. However it doesn't work at all.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    }
    int originalX, originalY;
    int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    int pointX1, pointY1;
    int pointX2, pointY2;
    Graphics g;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    Bitmap image;


    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                originalX = startX = e.X;
                originalY = startY = e.Y;
                 g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            }

        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            if (j < 10000000)
            {
                if (i != 0  )
                {
                    startX = pointX1;
                    startY = pointY1;
                }

                pointX2 = e.X;
                pointY2 = e.Y;
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(startX, startY), new Point(pointX2, pointY2));
                j++;
            }

        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            if (i <100000000 )
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    startX = pointX1;
                    startY = pointY1;
                }
                pointX1 = e.X;
                pointY1 = e.Y;
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(startX, startY), new Point(pointX1, pointY1));
            }

          }
            i++;
        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\student03\Documents\image\Sky2.jpg");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(pointX1, pointY1), new Point(originalX, originalY));
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        { 
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form add `this.KeyPreview = true;` under `InitializeComponent();` call :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
}
```

`Form.KeyPreview` is a boolean field/property that indicates that your `Form` object is able to preview pressed key before it goes into focused `Control` element.

**EDIT:**

To be able to remove lines you're drawing you have to modify everything in your code. But starting from the beginning. You should make some kind of structure called `Line` to store information about drawing item :

```
public struct Line
{
    public Point StartingPoint;
    public Point EndingPoint;
}
```

Then in your `Form1` code you should remove these fields :

```
int originalX, originalY;
int startX, startY, endX, endY;
int pointX1, pointY1;
int pointX2, pointY2;
Graphics g;
```

And replace them with these :

```
List<Line> lines;
Line current;
```

Now you should instantiate `lines` in your constructor :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    lines = new List<Line>();
}
```

Doing so you have a reference to the lines you will be creating and you have one object that will hold currently making line.

Next thing is that you're drawing directly on the image. I would recommend storing original image as a reference and modify copy of the image in your case it would require to add new field to the `Form1` :

```
Image originalImage;
```

And inside your `button2_Click` :

```
originalImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\student03\Documents\image\Sky2.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = originalImage.Clone();
```

Proceeding to the drawing section. Modify contents of `pictureBox1_MouseDown` into something like :

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        current = new Line();
        current.StartingPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
}
```

Now you have the current line filled with start position and you can proceed to modifying `pictureBox1_MouseUp` :

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
{
    current.EndingPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    lines.Add(current)
    pictureBox1.Image = originalImage.Clone();
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    if (i <100000000 )
    {
        foreach(Line l in lines)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, l.StartingPoint, l.EndingPoint);
        }     
    }
}
i++;
```

Almost the same logic applies to the `pictureBox1_MouseMove` but instead of adding `current` line to `lines` list, you have to draw it at the end :

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = originalImage.Clone();
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    if (i <100000000 )
    {
        foreach(Line l in lines)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, l.StartingPoint, l.EndingPoint);
        }     
    }
    current.EndingPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, current.StartingPoint, current.EndingPoint);
}
i++;
```

Then to remove the line you just have to remove last item in your lines collection and redraw image :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
{ 
    if ( lines.RemoveAt(lines.Count - 1) )
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = originalImage.Clone();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        foreach(Line l in lines)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, l.StartingPoint, l.EndingPoint);
        }  
    }
}
```

Even though it will work it's very unefficient because you're drawing on the image itself and not in the `pictureBox1` control. I would recommend you to use `pictureBox1.Paint` event for painting on top of the image instead.

Comment: omg thanks! it work perfectly! However i cant seems to find a way to use backspace and delete the lines that i had drawn. Could you help me out with that too?

Comment: @VernonPichu Currently it's almost impossible because you're not storing the drawing informations anywhere besides the screen. But I'll update this answer later with what you should do to be able to remove lines.

Comment: thank you very much. yea, i understand i am not storing any data on the drawing. Do update me, its a real big help for me thanks.

Comment: @VernonPichu I've added code to store/remove lines. Later on if you want I can update this to use efficient methods of drawing.